# Any downside on showing the same CSS Animation multiple times on a webpage?

Tags: css, performance, browser, html-rendering

I managed to put the same bootstrap spinner animation behind my lazyloaded images through CSS `position: relative` and `z-index` on my masonry grid. After images are loaded the loaded images are displayed above (z-index) the animation and i **do not** remove them. They just run behind the images.

Any downside on doing this with regards to webpage & browser rendering and so on performance, because my site uses infinite scroll and a lot of images are coming into view?

For the mentioned animation I'm using the following:

```css
.lodi:before,
.fa-pulse {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 1s infinite steps(8);
  animation: fa-spin 1s infinite steps(8)
}

@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}

.fa-rotate-90 {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your set up, but if you are saying multiple animations remain running then maybe a downside could be user-device battery drain?

Comment: Yes, there are potential downsides. Stack Overflow isn't really a place for lists, and it seems like the downsides are pretty well known; you have animations, which use CPU/GPU/memory resources. Separately, the indentation on the CSS was confusing, so I formatted it.